# how correctly disable wakeup pin in STM32f0?

Tags: stm32, sleep

We need to disable wake up pin in some time, during stm32f0 run. we have used

```
HAL_PWR_DisableWakeUpPin(PWR_WAKEUP_PIN1);
```

but it doesn't work. Should we do something else?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Wakeup pins need to be explicitely enabled. Did you? Can wakeup be from another source? Are you sure it's wakep and not reset?

Comment: @Jeroen3 thanks for the comment. Yes I've enable by this: HAL_PWR_DisableWakeUpPin   function. We have to have one button as toggle button for wakeup and standby (I think the main challenge is this).

Comment: @Jeroen3 I've tried to enable/disable the wake up pin. If we can do this, the problem can be solved in another way. but it didn't work. I've used HAL_PWR_DisableWakeUpPin() but it doesn't disable wake up pin

Comment: Go to the bare metal registers (no HAL) and see if that works.

Comment: @Jeroen3 I'm reading and checking ...